# Removing from Red & Black Tree issue

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures, binary-search-tree, red-black-tree

i think that the problem is root being null. WOuld someone one teach me how to do it the proper way ? Because i don't know why it is null ... I think the remove function is well implemented, but due to root being null it doesn't continue executing. Help please.
Any recommendation are welcome too :D

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        Tree t = new Tree("");
        String msg;
        String[] inputs;
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        ArrayList <String> palavras = new ArrayList <String>();
        int i = 0;



        while (true) {
            msg = sc.nextLine();
            if (msg.equals("")) {
                break;
            }


            inputs = msg.split(" ");

            i = 0;

            while (i < inputs.length) {
                palavras.add(inputs[i]);
                i++;
            }
        }



        i = 0;
        while (i < palavras.size()) {
            if (palavras.get(i).equals("REMOVE")) {
                t.remove(palavras.get(i+1));
                palavras.remove(i+1);
                i+=1;


            } else {
                t.insert(palavras.get(i).toLowerCase());
                i++;
            }
        }   

        t.postorder();
        t.preorder();
        t.inorder();



    }


**********************************************************

public void remove( String word) 
    {
        Node father=root;
        Node actual=root;
        boolean leftnode=true;


        if(root!=null){

            while(!word.equals(actual.str))
            {
              father=actual;      

              if(word.compareTo(actual.str)<0)
              {
                  leftnode=true;
                  actual=actual.left;
              }
              else{
                leftnode=false;
                actual=actual.right;
              }

              if(actual==null){
               return ;
              }
            }

            actual.occ = 0;   
        }
    }
```

Comment: Stepped through your code with a debugger yet? That should be your first guess, Eclipse even has a very comfortable one built in. Also, English variable names would help (at least me) to better understand your code.

Comment: yes i debbuged but couldn't understand why it's happenning

Comment: At some point some line of code must have set the root to null. Find that line. Maybe try with a hardcoded tree, i.e. build one for an array where you know what the tree is supposed to look like.

Comment: i've realized and edited saying that. better go find it!

Comment: still nothing. i'm completly lost...

Comment: Your code doesn't change any nodes, it just steps through the tree. There must be something wrong with the tree.

Comment: I didn't see the part when you initialize the `root` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was implementing Splay tree which works on the same concept as red black tree and at a point I was stuck like this. I will suggest you to draw the flow diagram of your code and then code it again. I hope your problem will be solved as mine.
you can refer [this](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/red-black-tree-set-2-insert/) and [this](http://www.stolerman.net/studies/cs521/red_black_trees.pdf) articles.